# Remove an array of elements from another array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have an array `array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and another array `array2 = [4,5]`.

The objective is to remove `array2`'s elements from `array1` with the least time complexity.

Final array is `[1,2,3,6]`

I know we can do something like this for every element

```
function remove(array, element) {
    return array.filter(e => e !== element);
}

let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
array2 = [4,5];
array2.forEach(el => {
    array1 = remove(array1, el);
});
```

How do i make it better?

Comment: Is this from an academic perspective, or is this just a problem you've got to solve as part of your work? [Lodash](https://lodash.com) is full of tools that can help with this if you're just trying to get this functionality into your application.

Comment: This is geometrically slow since it requires M x N passes. A faster solution involves sorting both arrays so you step through each of them once, but if order matters, that isn't a valid solution.

Comment: It's for academic purposes but the goal is to make it into a class and create a package of tools

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions for you :

```
var arr1 = [ 1, 2,3 ];
var arr2 = [1,2,4 ];
var result = arr1.filter(o1 => arr2.filter(o2 => o2 === o1).length === 0);
console.log(result);
```

Or you can use difference of [Loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and cleaner

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
const arr2 = [3,4]
const newArray = arr1.filter( x => !arr2.includes(x))
console.log(newArray)
```